# I want to use contents of String or Array in an If-else statement for iphone

Tags: iphone, arrays, nsstring, if-statement

I want to check to see if an array has "-" to activate a shipping method. I put "-" in since the array value will aways =2  and I need to IF ELSE by the contents. If the user doesn't not enter an address in the contents of the array looks like this:

```
Root   Array   (2items)  
Item 1 String   -  
Item 2 String   -
```

Here is the code for returning the array.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/arraySaveFile", documentsDirectory];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullFileName];
```

I want to write something like:

```
if ([fullFileName isEqualToString:@"-","-"]) 
{
[nnNEP EnableShipping];
}
else {
[nnNEP DisableShipping];
}
```

I just can't find the right or description on how to adjust it so that it compares both of the "-"'s in the array.

Comment: The editing of this post seems to have made it much more confusing than the original. What are you asking? Might be worth creating a new post and simplifying your question.

Comment: I wrote a new question. Hope it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if ([fullFileName isEuqalToString:@""])
{
    [nnNEP EnableShipping];
}
else
{
    [nnNEP DisableShipping];
}
```

Or:

```
if ([array count] == 0)
 {
    [nnNEP EnableShipping];
}
else
{
    [nnNEP DisableShipping];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question to only compare string values of both items in array,can you check it out?

Comment: Thanks for your time.. I posted a better question and it got answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/arraySaveFile", documentsDirectory];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullFileName];

if ([fullFileName isEqualToString:@""]) {
    [nnNEP EnableShipping];
}
else {
    [nnNEP DisableShipping];
}

if ([array count] == 0) {
    [nnNEP EnableShipping];
}
else {
    [nnNEP DisableShipping];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.. I posted a better question and it got answered.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did a stringWithFormat into fullFileName, it's never empty or nil so it's pointless to check that.

So then you want the array contents check - since you can send messages to nil it doesn't matter if the array is empty or nil, this will work the same way.

```
if ( array.count == 0 ) 
    [nnNEP EnableShipping];
else 
    [nnNEP DisableShipping];
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question because the value would have always been 2 items.

Comment: Thanks for your time.. I posted a better question and it got answered.